# How to merge users across different drives

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I just finished a new computer build and am trying to find a way to get the files from an old hard drive. The old hard drive was from a different Windows 10 computer, and is an HDD. I want to somehow merge the two different users on the SSD and HDD into one user that uses both drives.

If it is possible, I would also like some way to move the programs to the SSD, while keeping the files on the HDD.

Answer (score 1):

It's exceedingly difficult to move program files from one install of Windows on one drive to another drive running a different instance of Windows and get them to work.

Same with user profile folders.

The correct way to do this is:

For the User Profiles: Create the user accounts you wish, then copy the user files from the older profile folders to the profile folders of the new users you've created.

For programs: Just reinstall the programs on the new Windows instance. If there is application data for the programs you can follow whatever methods are appropriate for each application to import or migrate this data.

There are ample guides online, including here on SuperUser, for installing programs to an alternate drive, and questions here ought only contain a single question.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll see if what you suggest works.